# How frequent are publicly known quid pro quo legislative promises, similar to the pipeline deal with Manchin?

Tags: united-states, legislative-process

It was recently announced that Manchin voted for the Inflation Reduction Act in exchange for [easier permits for the Mountain Valley pipeline](https://www.propublica.org/article/manchin-gas-pipeline-climate-change-bill). Are such publicly known deals commonplace in Congress? This is the first time I hear about such an arrangement but perhaps it's actually pretty common? Are there some other examples of such deals in the past?

NB: I'm not talking about deals that happen *within* a single act of Congress, such [Christmas Tree bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_bill). I'm talking about deals where Congress passes legislation A while promising that legislation B will be passed *in the future* for the sake of one or more Senators/Congressmen.

Comment: Logrolling aka vote trading is supposedly pretty common in any coalition government (which your example effectively is). Statistically studying it is pretty hard though because the commitments aren't recorded in the usual legislative records.

Comment: @Fizz yes, I imagine backroom deals are extremely common, but this is the first time I'm hearing about such a future-looking deal in public - and not even as a "rumor", it looks like everyone involved explicitly acknowledges it.

Comment: Aside: one could take this case as an illustration of [Riker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Theory_of_Political_Coalitions#Size_Principle_and_Minimal_Size_Coalitions) on minimal-size coalitions...

Comment: But what exactly makes this example special? AFAICT from he article you link the D leadership has *not* commented on the deal. It only exists as such as the claims of some activists (and Manchin maybe), as far as I can tell. "The White House and Senate Democratic Leader Chuck Schumer’s office did not respond to requests for comment."

Comment: There are no direct quotes from Manchin  in the piece, so it's hard to say what *he* claimed exactly the deal was. So basically, are you looking for one-sided claims of vote-trading deals?

Comment: @Fizz you are right, it's actually not as explicit as I've thought. Then yes, I'm looking for a history of such one-sided quid pro quo claims.